# CREA DDF search engine

Tags: search, properties, idx, ddf

I have designed my real estate website and am looking for a code to have a CREA search engine integrated onto my website. I have acquired my credentials(username and password) from CREA so all that is left is the code that would get the listing data from CREA(Canadian Real Estate Association) board and display a search engine on my property search page from which properties can be searched for. Anyone's help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register as a `Technology partner` at `crea` website.

once approved, they will ask for `$500` for `5 feeds`.

After payment, they will share credentials and 2,3 technical documents by using those you can access data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a realtor you don't need to register as a technology partner. If you already have a CREA username and password then you need to set up your own feed by logging in here and following the instructions: https://www.crea.ca/technology/realtor-ca-for-realtors/realtor-ca-tools/realtor-ca-ddf/

Once you've set up the feed you need to get the code that does the work. If you're on Wordpress you can use Realtypress https://realtypress.ca/. It works great and is easy to configure.

However, if you're on some other platform such as Wix or Squarespace it's much more difficult. You will probably need the help of a experienced web developer.